# Render different image depending on Case Status

Tags: visualforce, case, service-cloud-console, images

Can I have a VF page that is a Top SideBar for a Case in Service Cloud Console. Can I have if show a different image depending on what the Case status is?

For example, if the case Status is changed to "Repair" I want a different image showing then if case status is changed to "Shipping".

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how big the image you're wanting to render is, but if is simply an icon you could first consider a simple formula field that renders an image in the details panel for the case that is in context i.e.

```
formula:IF(IsClosed,IMAGE("url for image if closed","case is closed"),IMAGE("url for case open","case is still open"))
```

If you do need to use a VF page, then you could leverage logic such as the following to conditionally render one of a number of images;

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="none">
<apex:image value="url to image for closed status" rendered="{!case.isClosed}"/>
<apex:image value="url to image for open status" rendered="{!NOT(case.isClosed)}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

@user5428 Did you applied VF code. If so, could you please paste your code. I have a similar requirement like yours.